# Why apt-get prompt me to run -f install and it cannot be run properly?

Tags: installation, apt

Why apt-get prompt me to run -f install and it cannot be run properly?

When I am trying to install some software through `apt-get install xxx`, it prompts me to run:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But when I run `apt-get -f install`, another error happens:

```
...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkfile4' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'kollision' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexempi3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'picmi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'kdenetwork' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgsl0-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 8041 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6:amd64 2.17-0ubuntu5 (using .../libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) ...
De-configuring libc6:i386 ...

A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory:
  '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so'
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove that copy of the C library or get it out of
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' and try again.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you get the same error try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```